# Impala sub-query returns strange result

Tags: hive, impala

I am running the below impala query and i am getting strange results. Why does the 2th query below returns zero results and how to overcome this. I am doing several data pipelines with multiple tables, so i have to use the "with" in the beginning.

```
1. Query: select * from test where name <> 'INSERT'
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 2  | DELETE |
| 2  | HELLO  |
+----+--------+
Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.13s


2. Query: with temp as (select * from test where name <> 'INSERT') select * from temp
Modified 0 row(s) in 0.23s


3. Query: with temp as (select * from test where name <> 'HELLO') select * from temp
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 2  | DELETE |
| 1  | INSERT |
+----+--------+
Fetched 2 row(s) in 0.12s


It should give the record names with 'HELLO' and 'DELETE' for the 2nd query. but its giving no results. Also noticed the output says "modified", so i am guessing its trying to execute it as DML.

Note : Using Impala Shell v2.11.0-cdh5.14.2

The same query works fine in hive.
```

Comment: What if you try to do `explain ...` on that 2nd query? Does it look similar to 3rd?

Comment: PLAN-ROOT SINK                                                                     |
| |                                                                                  |
| 01:EXCHANGE [UNPARTITIONED]                                                        |
| |                                                                                  |
| 00:SCAN HDFS [hello.temp]                                                          |
|    partitions=1/1 files=3 size=26B                                                 |
|    predicates: name != 'HELLO'

Comment: Yes it looks exactly same except the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work on my side

```sql
with temp as (SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 'DELETE' AS name
   UNION SELECT 'HELLO' AS name
   UNION SELECT 'INSERT' AS name) AS subq
WHERE name <> 'INSERT')
select * from temp;
```

```sql
+---------+
|  name   |
+---------+
| HELLO   |
| DELETE  |
+---------+
2 rows selected (0.118 seconds)
```

Could you post the `EXPLAIN PLAN` of your second query?

Comment: Sorry took a while to reply. Below is the response from explain.  

| 01:EXCHANGE [UNPARTITIONED]                                                        |
| |                                                                                  |
| 00:SCAN HDFS [hello.temp]                                                          |
|    partitions=1/1 files=3 size=26B                                                 |
|    predicates: name != 'INSERT'                                                    |

Comment: I executed your query and still no results with Impala shell. surprisingly no results for other values in the where conditions too. The same query works fine in Hive CLI

Comment: Sorry, took a while to answer back. Look at this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xwou427HfEgWrNttwkFPLB/0) . It's on Postgres but should be exactly the same result with Impala